# Email does not send in Laravel API after writing to database

Tags: angularjs, laravel, amazon-ec2, sendgrid

I have an AngularJS 1.5 application which is working with a Laravel 5.2 API and I'm trying to send emails at different points in the application. So I'm able to send data to Laravel and it gets recorded in the tables I specify but when it gets to sending a confirmation email it gives me this error with an HTTP status code of 500: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Odd thing is, it works perfectly fine in local development on my laptop. But the same functions on the AWS EC2 instance and it fails when it gets to sending any email. I'm using SendGrid to manage sending emails but I don't think I need to change any settings for that.

For Example:

```
    $emailUser = array();
    $emailUser['email'] = $request->email;
    $emailUser['first_name'] = $request->first_name;
    $emailUser['last_name'] = $request->last_name;
    $emailUser['randomStr'] = str_random(36);
    $emailUser['remove_dtm'] = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(2);

    //Add a password reset set to 2 weeks out for the user to register
    DB::table('password_resets')->insert([
        'email' => $emailUser['email'], 
        'token' => $emailUser['randomStr'], 
        'remove_dtm' => $emailUser['remove_dtm']
        ]);

    Mail::send('email.registered_user', $emailUser, function($message) use ($emailUser)
    {   $message->to($emailUser['email'], $emailUser['first_name'] . ' ' . $emailUser['last_name']);
        $message->from('WSCUSTOMERPO@waterstoneco.com', 'Waterstone Faucets');
        $message->replyTo('WSCUSTOMERPO@waterstoneco.com', 'Waterstone Faucets');
        $message->subject("Welcome to the Waterstone Faucets Portal!");
    });
```

When I try to reset a user's password it will create the record in the `password_reset` table but not send the email on the live site. Again the same function works fine on my laptop. I checked that I'm posting on the Angular side and Laravel API is expecting a post HTTP call when running this function.

What am I missing here?

Thank you greatly for your help!

Comment: Are you using smtp? Your live environment may be blocking it.

Comment: Check your spam box.

Comment: trying setting driver to log, just to check if the trouble is caused with email driver and not with the code

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to check here,

1: Are you sure you have your `.env` file set up to use the correct SMTP server settings to use SendGrid.  If you forgot to set this up in your `.env` you will be using the internal mail function.  Instead of using SendGrid, I would suggest keeping it inside of Amazon for more reliability. Switching over to Amazon SES may be a great option for you.

2: If you are using the internal mail system, there is a really good article about mail from Amazon EC2 instances here: http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/07/sending-email-from-ec2.html

Just a reminder for number 1 for others that may have come here looking for help.  To set your mail service in Laravel to use an smtp service, open your `config/mail.php` file and set the driver to use your provider (if provided by laravel).  This can be done by edit the file directly or setting the environment variable `MAIL_DRIVER` in your `.env` file.